# "They ventured nervously into the water." & "He nervously ventured out onto the ice."— Difference between "ventured nervously" & "nervously ventured"?

Tags: difference, adverbs, adverb-placement

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/venture_2):
**(1)** *They ventured **nervously** into the water*.
my variant:
**(2)** *They **nervously** ventured into the water*.
What's the difference between (1) and (2)?

[britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/venture):
**(3)** *He **nervously** ventured out onto the ice*.
my variant:
**(4)** *He ventured **nervously** out onto the ice*.
What's the difference between (3) and (4)?

Answer (score 1):

> They ventured ***nervously*** into the water.

> They ***nervously*** ventured into the water.

For both pairs, each example means the same as its counterpart, but [*ventured nervously* is more common than *nervously ventured*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ventured+nervously%2Cnervously+ventured&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3).

**Additional Information**

A few other similar comparisons with different adverbs yield mixed results:

[*ventured carefully* is more common than *carefully ventured*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ventured+carefully%2Ccarefully+ventured&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3), but [*courageously ventured*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ventured+courageously%2Ccourageously+ventured&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3) and [*quickly ventured*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ventured+quickly%2Cquickly+ventured&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3) are more common than their counterparts.

[*ventured recklessly* caught up with *recklessly ventured*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ventured+recklessly%2Crecklessly+ventured&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3) in the early 1900s, and the two constructions are about equally common in the past 40 years.

A broad-based comparison between [*ventured+ADV* and *ADV+ventured*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ventured+*_ADV%2C*_ADV+ventured&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3) didn't yield results relevant to this question as the listed adverbs (the 10 most common occurrences) are not the forms derived from adjectives.